# quadratic equation, value calculation for x by classic method - time and space complexity of iterative implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm, iteration, time-complexity, space-complexity

This is the code covering above problem:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a0, a1, a2;
    cin >> a0 >> a1 >> a2;
    double x;
    cin >> x;
    double w;
    w = 0;
    int array[] = { a0, a1, a2 };
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        w += array[j] * pow(x, i);
        j++;
    }
    cout << w;
    return 0;
}
```

According to my analysis both the time and the space complexity is constant. No matter how large the a0, a1, a2 and x are we have two iteration in for loop and the same number of variables so in the big-O notation it can be expressed as O(1). Could anyone relate?

Also not sure if pointers usage is correct in above code because I am new to c++ and some of its concepts still make me confused so the constructive criticism is way more than expected if there are any mistakes.

Comment: What is purpose of using pointers? You never use them as addresses.

Comment: I've changed the code and it works without pointers

Comment: The errors were: non-initialized values of variables or something like that

Comment: The last part of the question is now unrelated.